# Google Slides API replace the image but not remained its photograph and size

Tags: shapes, google-slides-api

First I got the old image object as below:

[image]

I applied Google Slides API and  set the same size code as below:

[image]

It can be seen as I set the same size of the pics but the shape is different.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problem with the size and shape of the image, here is the document that could help you on [sizing and positioning of page elements](https://developers.google.com/slides/how-tos/transform).

> When you create a page element, you can specify a size and transform
>   that provide a certain visual result. However, the API may replace
>   your provided values with other ones that yield the same visual
>   appearance. ***In general, if you write a size using the API, you are not
>   guaranteed to be returned the same size.*** However, you should get the
>   same results if you take the [transform](https://developers.google.com/slides/concepts/transforms) into account.

Here are some important facts about Transforms and Page Elements.

> This guide describes the underlying concepts used in transforming
>   (that is, moving, rotating, scaling, and shearing) page elements,
>   focusing especially on the underlying [affine transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) and its
>   operations.
>
> For more about how to use affine transforms to achieve specific
>   results, see the [Size and Position Shapes](https://developers.google.com/slides/how-tos/transform) guide.
>
> The visual size and position of a page element are controlled by two
>   properties: size and transform. The size describes the ideal or native
>   size of the page element being created. The transform specifies a
>   two-dimensional affine transform matrix that specifies how an object
>   at its native size is transformed to result in its final visual
>   appearance.

Just explore the documentation and apply it in your code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I still don't understand affine transform, but Thank you for all your answer.